# Class 'Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Mostviewed' not found

Tags: class

i am trying to display most viewed products on homepage. getting following error.

```
class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Mostviewed extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract {
public
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $storeId = Mage::app() - > getStore() - > getId();
    $products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection') - > addOrderedQty() - > addAttributeToSelect('*') - > addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'small_image')) - > setStoreId($storeId) - > addStoreFilter($storeId) - > addViewsCount();
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status') - > addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility') - > addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products);
    $products - > setPageSize(5) - > setCurPage(1);
    $this - > setProductCollection($products);
}
```

}

```
Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Mostviewed' not found in  C:\xampp\htdocs\ifasonx\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php on line 491
```

refference:- http://www.magikcommerce.com/blog/how-to-show-most-viewed-best-selling-products-in-magento-store/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means that the autoloader is failing to load a file containing the class. The most likely cause is probably one of:

1. There isn't actually a file `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Mostviewed.php` because of a typo in the filename.
2. The file is there but has incorrect file permissions, meaning the webserver cannot read it.
3. You have [compilation](https://www.siteground.com/kb/magento-compilation/) mode enabled. This would require re-compilation after creating the new block class.